# Create session variable in hosted service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

I have an MVC app developed with NET5, it uses session variables for user authorization.

The issue is that I am implementing a hosted service that gets up in the startup.cs class of my MVC project, this service performs checks every so often and changes states in the database, in which it stores the username who made it.

the action, for that I need to create a session variable, but the session object does not allow it.

Try using IHttpContextAccessor Dependency Injection, but the HttpContext object is as null.

Then I tried to create the context with DefaultHttpContext, but debugging it throws the following error:

```
Session = 'httpContext.Session'
```

threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Here is the code of my service:

```
public class ProcessingService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private int executionCount = 0;
    private Timer _timer;
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider { get; }


    private readonly ILogger<ProcessingService> _logger;
    private readonly IPlatFormSessionService _platFormSessionService;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;



    public ProcessingService(ILogger<ProcessingService> logger, IPlatFormSessionService platFormSessionService, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _platFormSessionService = platFormSessionService;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service running.");
        _timer = new Timer(DoWorkAsync, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    private async void DoWorkAsync(object state)
    {
        var count = Interlocked.Increment(ref executionCount);
        using (var serviceScope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var userSession = _platFormSessionService.GetSessionInfo<UserDto>(SessionVars.BackGroundServices);
            if (userSession == null)
            {
                UserDto userDto = new UserDto
                {
                    Id = -9999,
                    CompanyId = 1,
                    UserName = "ProcessingService"
                };
                var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = serviceScope.ServiceProvider };
                _platFormSessionService.SetSessionInfo(httpContext, userDto, SessionVars.BackGroundServices);//This method only creates the session variable
            }
        }

        _logger.LogInformation("WorkflowProcessingService.Timed Hosted Service is working. Count: {Count}", count);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service is stopping.");
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Could you give me your help?

Comment: A hosted service has no HttpContext as it's not involved in request processing, much less a session. It runs in the background, far longer than any user session. At any moment there may be 100s of concurrent sessions. Which one of those should the service use?

Comment: I suppose `IPlatFormSessionService` is your business logic service you want to reuse in background worker. Tightly coupling it with web session was bad idea, you cannot reuse this service until you refactor it and leave all web stuff in web layer.

Comment: They are right, I will have to approach it in another way. Thank you very much for his responses.